# Vectorize Sliding Window Dot Product

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, numpy-ndarray, dot-product

I have two large vectors (of equal length) that I'm calculating a sliding window dot product for:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
b = np.array([11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66])

out = np.array(
    [[a[0]*b[0]+a[1]*b[1]+a[2]*b[2]],
     [a[1]*b[1]+a[2]*b[2]+a[3]*b[3]],
     [a[2]*b[2]+a[3]*b[3]+a[4]*b[4]],
     [a[3]*b[3]+a[4]*b[4]+a[5]*b[5]],
    ])

[[154]
 [319]
 [550]
 [847]]
```

Of course, I can call the dot product function but if the window/vector length is large then it is not as efficient as the following code:

```
window = 3
result = np.empty([4,1])
result[0] = a[0]*b[0]+a[1]*b[1]+a[2]*b[2]
for i in range(3):
    result[i+1] = result[i]-a[i]*b[i]+a[i+window]*b[i+window]

[[154]
 [319]
 [550]
 [847]]
```

Here, we are leveraging the fact that the `i+1th` dot product is similar to the `ith` dot product. That is,

```
result[i+1] = result[i]-a[i]*b[i]+a[i+window]*b[i+window]
```

How can I convert my for loop into a vectorized function so that the computation can utilize the information from the `ith` step so as to reduce the computational redundancy while minimizing the amount of memory needed.

**UPDATE**

I actually needed:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
b = np.array([11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88])

out = np.array(
    [a[0]*b[0]+a[1]*b[1]+a[2]*b[2]+a[3]*b[3]]+a[4]*b[4]]+a[5]*b[5],
     a[0]*b[1]+a[1]*b[2]+a[2]*b[3]+a[3]*b[4]]+a[4]*b[5]]+a[5]*b[6],
     a[0]*b[2]+a[1]*b[3]+a[2]*b[4]+a[3]*b[5]]+a[4]*b[6]]+a[5]*b[7],
    ])

[1001
 1232
 1463]
```

So `a` would be slid across `b` and dot products would be calculated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use partial sums for O(n) complexity:

```
ps = np.r_[0, np.cumsum(a*b)]
ps[3:]-ps[:-3]
# array([154, 319, 550, 847])
```

Or a variant that is closer to your original `for` loop and avoids very large partial sums:

```
k = 3
d = a*b
d[k:] -= d[:-k].copy()
np.cumsum(d)[k-1:]
# array([154, 319, 550, 847])
```

**Update** to match the updated **Q**.

This is now indeed a convolution, so @Divakar's solution more or less applies. Only, you'd convolve `a[::-1]` and `b` directly. If speed is a problem you may try and replace `np.convolve` with `scipy.signal.fftconvolve` which depending on the sizes of your operands may be significantly faster. For very small operands or operands of vastly different lengths, though, you may even lose some speed, so be sure to try both methods:

```
np.convolve(b, a[::-1], 'valid')
scipy.signal.fftconvolve(b, a[::-1], 'valid')
```

Comment: Yup. This could be molded as the theoretical stuff that could be [`published`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42934806/vectorize-sliding-window-dot-product/42934875?noredirect=1#comment72969583_42934875) :)

Comment: Thanks! This looks like the right answer. I'm not familiar with np.r_ but I assume that it is better than instantiating an empty array first `x = np.empty(len(a)+1)`, filling the array with `np.cumsum(a*b, out=x[1:])`, and then setting the first element to zero via `x[0] = 0`. I have read the docs on [np.r](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) and it obviously produces the correct result but would you mind providing a little more information as I'm sure it will be new for others too.

Comment: @slaw no, your preallocation approach is better performance wise, I was just lazy. Be sure also to look at the variant I just added, because if your vectors are 10^8 long then it may be crucial to keep the sizes of partial sums in check.

Comment: @PaulPanzer thanks for educating me with such a well thought out answer!

Comment: @slaw Thanks for your kind words. I just fixed a little bug in the second solution. The in-place assignment `d[k:] -= d[:-k]` was unsafe. So a `.copy()` had to be added. Please make sure to include it if you are using this code.

Comment: @PaulPanzer `.copy()` noted. Thanks! Still surprised that the dot product can be calculated in `O(n)` in this way as I would've never spotted it using `cumsum`. Did you know this prior? Perhaps a link to relevant resources would be helpful to others.

Comment: @slaw `cumsum` is essentially a discrete [antiderivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative). The sliding sums correspond to definite integrals. All I'm doing is a discrete version of calculating a definite integral as a difference of the antiderivative evaluated at the endpoints of the integration interval.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138757/discussion-between-slaw-and-paul-panzer).

Answer (score 0):

**Approach #1**

Use [`np.convolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html) on element-wise multiplication between the two inputs and with a kernel of all ones and `size=3` -

```
np.convolve(a*b,np.ones(3),'valid')
```

---

**Approach #2**

Since we are simply summing elements in a window, we can also use [`uniform_filter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.uniform_filter1d.html), like so -

```
from scipy.ndimage.filters import uniform_filter1d as unif1d

def uniform_filter(a,W):
    hW = (W-1)//2
    return W*unif1d(a.astype(float),size=W, mode='constant')[hW:-hW]

out = uniform_filter(a*b,W=3)
```

### Benchmarking

Loopy approach -

```
def loopy_approach(a,b):
    window = 3
    N = a.size-window+1

    result = np.empty([N,1])
    result[0] = a[0]*b[0]+a[1]*b[1]+a[2]*b[2]
    for i in range(N-1):
        result[i+1] = result[i]-a[i]*b[i]+a[i+window]*b[i+window]
    return result
```

Timings and verification -

```
In [147]: a = np.random.randint(0,100,(1000))
     ...: b = np.random.randint(0,100,(1000))
     ...: 

In [148]: out0 = loopy_approach(a,b).ravel()
     ...: out1 = np.convolve(a*b,np.ones(3),'valid')
     ...: out2 = uniform_filter(a*b,W=3)
     ...: 

In [149]: np.allclose(out0,out1)
Out[149]: True

In [150]: np.allclose(out0,out2)
Out[150]: True

In [151]: %timeit loopy_approach(a,b)
     ...: %timeit np.convolve(a*b,np.ones(3),'valid')
     ...: %timeit uniform_filter(a*b,W=3)
     ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 2.27 ms per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 7 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.2 µs per loop
```

Comment: Yes, I know I can do that but FFT is actually `O(nlogn)` while the solution above is actually `O(n)`. Hence the request to vectorize it in place of the for loop. Again, both the vectors and the window size will be very long and so the convolve method would be about an order of magnitude worse.

Comment: @slaw I think you are un-necessarily bringing in computational complexity here. These convolutions are implemented in C/fortran AFAIK and as such would be as good as any vectorized method in NumPy/Scipy, etc.

Comment: @Divakar what is `y` in the 2nd approach please? Also, I think since OP expects the result to be 2D, your first approach should be `np.convolve(a*b,np.ones(3),'valid')[:, np.newaxis]`

Comment: @kmario23 Adding a new axis is trivial here, don't think OP would mind it either way. Thanks for pointing it out nevertheless!

Comment: @slaw Added runtime tests if they could persuade you to re-think on your complexity side thoughts.

Comment: @Divakar I am trying to reproduce some published work where they proved the time complexity as I had mentioned above. I've already implemented the method with convolve and am exploring the faster alternative in my original post. The array lengths are on the order of 100 million data points with a window size of 400-2000. Thus, the time complexity should matter and I would like to compare the two. Again, I already have code that uses convolve but would like to vectorize the `O(n)` algorithm if possible for comparison. Note that the dot product is actually in a doubly nested for loop in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach using [strides](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.strides.html) is:

```
In [12]: from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided
In [13]: def using_strides(a, b, w=3):
              shape = a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1] - w + 1, w)
              strides = a.strides + (a.strides[-1],)
              res = np.sum((as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides) * \ 
                            as_strided(b, shape=shape, strides=strides)), axis=1)
              return res[:, np.newaxis]


In [14]: using_strides(a, b, 3)
Out[14]: 
array([[154],
       [319],
       [550],
       [847]])
```

Comment: Yes, using strides is fine but for longer vectors (100 million elements) and larger windows this becomes more expensive due to the amount of redundant computations. The time complexity for the non-redundant version is `O(n)`